# Testing an Angular 2 component with async-populated child components

Tags: testing, angular

I am trying to write tests for a compound component, populated with an observable, but as this is one of the first Angular2 tests I am writing.

I have a component named `ListContainerComponent` which is populated using Observable `list$` with children instances of `ListItemComponent`.

`ListContainerComponent`'s template follows:

```
<list-item
    *ngFor="let listItem of (list$ | async)" [item]="listItem"></list-item>
```

Works great in the browser. The tests however break on that the `[item]` is allegedly not a known property of `ListItemComponent` which is not exactly true, as it does have `@Input() item` in it.

```
import { TestBed, async, ComponentFixture } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { ListContainerComponent } from './list-container.component';
import { Store, StoreModule } from '@ngrx/store';

import * as fromRoot from '../../../reducers';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { reducer } from '../../../reducers/list.reducer';

describe('Component: ListContainer', () => {
    let storeStub;
    let component: ListContainerComponent;
    let fixture: ComponentFixture<ListContainerComponent>;
    let element: HTMLElement;

    beforeEach(() => {
        storeStub = {
            items: []
        };

        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            declarations: [
                ListContainerComponent
            ],
            providers: [
                {provide: Store, useValue: storeStub}
            ],
            imports: [
                StoreModule.provideStore(reducer),
            ]
        })
        .compileComponents();

        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ListContainerComponent);
        component = fixture.componentInstance;
        element = fixture.nativeElement;
    });

    it('should populate list', async(() => {
        component.list$ = Observable.of([
            {name: 'abc', value: 'content of abc'},
        ]};

        fixture.detectChanges();
        expect(element.querySelectorAll('h4').length).toBeGreaterThan(0);

    }));
});
```

Sorry I am not providing a working plunker, but I don't know yet how to create tests in plunker. I believe the mistaking I am making is an obvious one, probably showing my wrong approach, and easy to spot by those in the know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the `ListItemComponent` to the `declarations`, just like you would in the real application. The `TestBed` is to configure a module from scratch, just for the test environment. So whatever you would need for the component to work in the real app, you need to add it (or a mock of it) to the test configuration.

```
declarations: [
  ListContainerComponent,
  ListItemComponent
],
```

Comment: Thanks, a good point, when I fixed it though, I got compaints about the `$list` property being undefined:
`undefined is not a constructor (evaluating 'store.let(...)')`

Comment: my async populated, child component inputs also show up as null, despite the value being set properly in the parent component. I'm still looking for a solution to this.